# Reassemble float from bytes inline

Tags: c, embedded, type-punning

I'm working with HiTech PICC32 on the PIC32MX series of microprocessors, but I think this question is general enough for anyone knowledgable in C. (This is almost equivalent to C90, with sizeof(int) = sizeof(long) = sizeof(float) = 4.)

Let's say I read a 4-byte word of data that represents a `float`. I can quickly convert it to its actual float value with:

```
#define FLOAT_FROM_WORD(WORD_VALUE) (*((float*) &(WORD_VALUE)))
```

But this only works for lvalues. I can't, for example, use this on a function return value like:

```
FLOAT_FROM_WORD(eeprom_read_word(addr));
```

Is there a short and sweet way to do this inline, i.e. without a function call or temp variable? To be honest, there's no HUGE reason for me to avoid a function call or extra var, but it's bugging me. There must be a way I'm missing.

**Added:** I didn't realise that `WORD` was actually a common typedef. I've changed the name of the macro argument to avoid confusion.

Comment: "But this only works for rvalues" You mean lvalues? Anyway, with optimizations your compiler should remove the function call anyway; just stick it in a function and look at the assembly to find out.

Comment: Corrected [l/r]value thing. Will look at assembly later.

Comment: I recommend you put this sort of thing in a platform-specific wrapper function to keep this platform-specific code confined to a small part of your project.

Comment: It's all platform specific — this code is specifically written for the PIC32MX[3/4]60F512L.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can run the trick the other way for return values

```
float fl;
*(int*)&fl = eeprom_read_word(addr);
```

or

```
#define WORD_TO_FLOAT(f)  (*(int*)&(f))

WORD_TO_FLOAT(fl) = eeprom_read_word(addr);
```

or as R Samuel Klatchko suggests

```
#define  ASTYPE(type, val) (*(type*)&(val))
ASTYPE(WORD,fl) = eeprom_read_word(addr);
```

Comment: If you wanted to generalize that further, you could make the type to treat the variable as a macro parameter `#define ASTYPE(var, type) (*(type*)&(var))` and then use it like `ASTYPE(fl, WORD) = ...`

Comment: Good suggestion, I'll add that to the answer

Comment: Quick and simple, I like it. Cheers.

Comment: make sure the endianness works out correctly with your read/write routines for the eeprom :)

Answer (score 3):

If this were GCC, you could do this:

```
#define atob(original, newtype) \
  (((union { typeof(original) i; newtype j })(original)).k)
```

Wow. Hideous. But the usage is nice:

```
int i = 0xdeadbeef;
float f = atob(i, float);
```

I bet your compiler doesn't support either the `typeof` operator nor the `union` casting that GCC does, since neither are standard behavior, but in the off-chance that your compiler can do `union` casting, that is your answer. Modified not to use `typeof`:

```
#define atob(original, origtype newtype) \
  (((union { origtype i; newtype j })(original)).k)

int i = 0xdeadbeef;
float f = atob(i, int, float);
```

Of course, this ignores the issue of what happens when you use two types of different sizes, but is closer to "what you want," i.e. a simple macro filter that returns a value, instead of taking an extra parameter. The extra parameters this version takes are just for generality.

If your compiler doesn't support `union` casting, which is a neat but non-portable trick, then there is no way to do this the "way you want it," and the other answers have already got it.

Comment: The sad thing is, Microchip actually make a GCC based compiler and they've technically released the source. However, I've never been able to coax it to compile on Linux.

Answer (score 1):

you can take the address of a temporary value if you use a const reference:

```
FLOAT_FROM_WORD(w) (*(float*)&(const WORD &)(w))
```

but that won't work in c :(

(c doesn't have references right? works in visual c++)

as others have said, be it an inlined function or a temp in a define, the compiler will optimize it out.

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer, more a suggestion.  Your FLOAT_FROM_WORD macro will be more natural to use and more flexible if it doesn't have a ; at the end

```
#define FLOAT_FROM_WORD(w) (*(float*)&(w))

fl = FLOAT_FROM_WORD(wd);
```

Answer (score 0):

It may not be possible in your exact situation, but upgrading to a C99 compiler would solve your problem too.

C99 has inline functions which, while acting like normal functions in parameters and return values, get improved efficiency in exactly this case with none of the drawbacks of macros.

Comment: HiTech don't make a C99 compiler, so... no can do :/